# how to get rows from a table where value of column occurs most in another table?

Tags: mysql, database

What I need to do is I need to get the rows from one table where a certain value in a column in another table occurs most. Here is the structure of the 2 tables:

```
 --------------------------------------------
 |schoolid|schoolname|schoolstate|schoolcity|
 --------------------------------------------
 |  1     | school a | New York  | New York |
 |  2     | school b | California|Las Angeles|
 |  3     | school c | Texas     | Dallas   |
 --------------------------------------------

 -----------------------------------------
 |studentid|studentname|studentschool|gpa|
 -----------------------------------------
 |  1      | John Doe  | school a    |3.1|
 |  2      | John Doe  | school c    |1.7|
 |  3      | John Doe  | school b    |2.8|
 |  4      | John Doe  | school a    |3.9|
 |  5      | John Doe  | school a    |3.0|
 -----------------------------------------
```

To reword my question, I need to select and order the schools by the amount of students in each school.

Comment: Hint:  This is a rather basic query that would typically involve a `JOIN`, a `GROUP BY` and an `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can use

```
select s.schoolname, (select count(s1.schoolid) from school s1 ,students st1 
 where    s1.schoolname=st1.studentschool and st1.studentschool=s.schoolname) 
studentCount from school s order by studentCount  desc;
```

## Or you can use(If you don't need to school which on has no student)

```
select s1.schoolname,count(*)studentcount  from school s1 ,students st1 
where s1.schoolname=st1.studentschool GROUP BY s1.schoolname order by  studentcount desc;
```